# Hide Information about the Slides in PowerPoint Presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I have number of PowerPoint presentations for monthly reports. There is often data/text/table/image that is associated with some of the slides. It is almost like a note. I would like to store it with the presentation slides. I have tried to store it somewhere else, but I often tend to forget those folders/files. By keeping the information right in the presentation, I can access it whenever I want, if the Manager asks more details about it.

Things I have tried:

1. As many do, create backup slides at the end. But that does not look good and is still located "far enough" from the original slides that it looses its effectiveness.
2. Slide Notes: They are useful, but they only take plain text, no image or any other formatted text.

Is there a way to hide or "mask" some useful information with the slides, that can be accessed if needed?

Thank you.
(**Note**: I am not expecting a large set of information, just few notes, or occasional image.)

Comment: You can add images in notes when in Notes Pages View. You can Hide objects using the Selection Pane.

Answer (score 0):

If your backup slides relate to the information on specific regular slides, this is fairly simple (assuming that this is for a slideshow).

Add the slides in each set of backup slides to a custom presentation.
Give the custom presentation a meaningful name.

On the slide that the backup slides relate to, add a link TO the custom presentation and put a check next to the Show & Return option.

Finally, HIDE all of the slides in the custom presentation(s) so users can't accidentally navigate to them.

Comment: thank you. After a bit of playing around, I was able to make this work. I created a custom presentation (which I did not know, you can do!). And then linked the parent slide to that presentation with checkbox checked to **show and return**. One question, though, hiding slides as you mentioned, only hides in the Slideshow, those hidden slides can still be viewed in normal view.

Comment: >> "One question, though, hiding slides as you mentioned, only hides in the Slideshow, those hidden slides can still be viewed in normal view"  

True.  You'd need to give the presentation in Slide Show view for this to work. If people will be viewing the presentation in Normal view, you'd need to put the "hidden" slides in a separate presentation that you link to. People could then Ctrl+Click the link to view the "hidden" slides.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense.